# What silhouette number do droids and playable species have?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion

What silhouette do the playable species and droids count as — 0, 1, or something else? The move power mentions silhouette but I couldn't find an explanation there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Chapter 6 of *Edge of the Empire*, on **page 212** there is **Table 6-6** which offers a quick comparison of character types with silhouettes.

Humanoid species/droids are typically classed as Silhouette 1, while anything smaller is Silhouette 0.

Chapter 7 has a similar chart for looking at the increasing sizes of ship types.

Comment: Tnx had overlooked that one chart!